# C++ sort() function algorithm

Tags: c++, string, sorting

Some days ago I wanted to use C++ `sort()` function to sort an array of strings, but I had a problem!

What algorithm does it use to sort the array? Is it a deterministic one or may it use different algorithms based on the type of the array?

Also, is there a clear time complexity analysis about it?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please **[edit]** your question with a [mcve] or [SSCCE (Short, Self Contained, Correct Example)](http://sscce.org)

Comment: Have you tried sorting this array of strings?

Comment: **would it work in less than 1 second(in the worst case)?** This is largely architecture dependent. On an i7, maybe, on an Atmega16, absolutely not.

Comment: ..."but I had a problem" - we're not mind readers. If you want help with a problem you need to describe what you're trying to do, what you actually tried (i.e. provide code), what behaviour you expected, and what behaviour you actually observed. See here: [How to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). If you have no interest in solving that problem, I'm unsure what it has to do with the remainder of your question.

Comment: You say "I had a problem!" but you never tell us what the problem was.

Comment: `the total size of them is less than 100,000 characters` Is that the sum of all `string.size()`? I think the most important part is the number of strings in the array - not the size of the individual string (unless the strings typically only differs on the last characters).

Answer (score 2):

> Does this function use the same algorithm for sorting numbers array and strings array?

It might or it might not. That is not specified by the standard.

> And if we use it to sort an array of strings which the total size of them is less than 100,000 characters, would it work in less than 1 second(in the worst case)?

It might or it might not. It depends on the machine you're running the program on. Even if it will work in less than 1 second in worst case on a particular machine, it would be difficult to prove. But you can get a decent estimation by measuring. A measurement only applies to the machine it was performed, of course.

Comment: Same algorithm: It's not specified by the standard, but it is very likely to use the same algorithm for all sorting.

Comment: @MartinBonner All I know that the standard does not mention anything about requiring the algorithm be same for all types. I share a hunch that having a different algorithm would not be worth it, but I couldn't say for certain since I haven't implemented all of the standard libraries.